# Title of localnotifiaction

Tags: ios4

I want to show local notification with different message title( "Error" ) and not as of the application's name. 
How can i achieve this.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I check and doing this is not possible. No property available for that.

Ravi Kumar Singh